# Find the length of the loop of the given curve: $x=3t-t^3$ $y=3t^2$

Tags: calculus

I used the arc length formula (where you take the integral of square root of x' squared + y' squared $\int \sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2}dt$) to get $t^3 + 3t + C$ which seems to be the wrong answer. Not sure what I did wrong. Please tell me the correct answer and why my solution was incorrect. Thanks

Comment: You integrated from where to where?

Comment: Plot the graph. There is a clear loop in it. That's what they want you to find the length of. You should set up a definite integral with the correct bounds and get a number (not an algebraic expression) as the answer. Link to plot: https://graphsketch.com/parametric?mode=para&eqn1_color=1&eqn1_x=3t-t%5E3&eqn1_y=3t%5E2&eqn2_color=2&eqn2_x=&eqn2_y=&eqn3_color=3&eqn3_x=&eqn3_y=&x_min=-17&x_max=17&y_min=-10.5&y_max=10.5&t_min=-10&t_max=10&x_tick=1&y_tick=1&x_label_freq=5&y_label_freq=5&do_grid=0&do_grid=1&bold_labeled_lines=0&bold_labeled_lines=1&line_width=4&image_w=850&image_h=525

Answer (score 4):

If the path described makes a loop, then there will be 2 values $t_1$ and $t_2$ such that $
\begin{bmatrix} x(t_1) \\ y(t_1) \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} x(t_2) \\ y(t_2) \end{bmatrix}
$ , so:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 3t_1 - t_1{}^3 \\ 3t_1{}^2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 3t_2 - t_2{}^3 \\ 3t_2{}^2 \end{bmatrix}$$

From $3t_1{}^2 = 3t_2{}^2$, we get $t_1 = -t_2$, and from $3t_1 - t_1{}^3 = -3t_1 + t_1{}^3$, we get that

$$t_1 = -\sqrt{3} \text{ and }t_2 = \sqrt{3}$$

Now the formula for parametrized path length is similar to the pythagorean formula, explicitly:

$$L = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} { \sqrt{ \left(\frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}t} \right)^2 + \left(\frac{{\rm d}x}{{\rm d}t} \right)^2 } {\rm d}t }$$

And filling in:

$$\begin{align}
%
L &= \int_{-\sqrt{3}}^{\sqrt{3}} { \sqrt{ \left(6t \right)^2 + \left(3 - 3t^2 \right)^2 } {\rm d}t }
%
\\ &= \int_{-\sqrt{3}}^{\sqrt{3}} { \sqrt{ 9t^4 + 18t^2 + 9 } {\rm d}t }
%
\\ &= \int_{-\sqrt{3}}^{\sqrt{3}} { \left \vert 3t^2 + 3 \right \vert {\rm d}t }
%
\\ &= t^3 + 3t ~\bigg\vert_{t = -\sqrt{3}}^{t = \sqrt{3}} 
%
\\ &= 12 \sqrt{3}
%
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Too long for comment (**it's not an answer**)
$$
x'=3(1-t^2), \enspace y'=3\cdot 2t\\
x'^2 + y'^2 = 3^2 [(1-t^2)^2 + (2t)^2] = 3^2 (1 - 2t^2 + t^4 + 4t^2) = 3^2 (1 + t^2)^2\\
\sqrt{x'^2 + y'^2} = 3(1+t^2)\\
\int \sqrt{x'^2 + y'^2}\,dt = t^3 + 3t + C
$$
Why it "seems to be the wrong answer"?

Comment: Please see my comment to the OP. Plot the curve, the length of the obvious loop must be what the question was asking for. Definite integral, not an indefinite one.

Comment: Because the question is the length of the loop of the curve. So first some analysis has to be performed to study the curve and find the right interval for which the loop is performed.

Answer (score 0):

There are three places where $x(t)=0$, namely $t\in\{0,\pm\sqrt3\}$.

Of these, only $\pm\sqrt3$ yields equal values for $y(t)$, so the bounds of the loop must be $[-\sqrt3,\sqrt3]$.

Integrating the differential arc length, you get
$$t^3+3t|_{-\sqrt3}^\sqrt3=6\sqrt3-(-6\sqrt3)=12\sqrt3$$

Answer (score 0):

First one has to determine $t_1$ and $t_2$, with $t_1<t_2$ such that
$$
(x(t_1),y(t_1))=(x(t_2),y(t_2)).
$$
We have:
$$
(x(t),y(t))=(x(s),y(s))\iff \left\{
\begin{array}{lcl}
3t-t^3-3s+s^3&=&0\\
3s^2-3t^2&=&0
\end{array}\right..
$$
Since we are looking for $t_1$ and $t_2$, with $t_1<t_2$, we deduce from the second equation of the system above that $s=-t$. The first equation of our system then becomes:
$$
3t-t^3=t(3-t^2)=0,
$$
i.e. 
$$
t=0,\pm\sqrt{3}.
$$
Hence
$$
t_1=-\sqrt3=-t_2,\quad t_2=\sqrt3.
$$
The length of the loop is then:
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\sqrt{(x'(t))^2+(y'(t))^2}\,dt&=&\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\sqrt{(3-3t^2)^2+(6t)^2}\,dt=\int_{-t_2}^{t_2}\sqrt{3^2[(1-t^2)^2+4t^2]}\,dt\\
&=&2\cdot3\int_0^{t_2}\sqrt{1-2t^2+t^4+4t^2}\,dt=6\int_0^{t_2}\sqrt{1+2t^2+t^4}\,dt\\
&=&6\int_0^{t_2}\sqrt{(1+t^2)^2}\,dt=6\int_0^{t_2}(1+t^2)\,dt\\
&=&6\left[t+\frac13t^3\right]_0^{t_2}=6t_2+2t_2^3=6\sqrt3+2\cdot3\sqrt3=12\sqrt3.
\end{eqnarray}